# Configuring API Gateway to respect x-amz-log-type for lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have a lambda function I am invoking from outside AWS.

I would like to use [the LogType config option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax) but I am not sure how to successfully pass this through API Gateway to be used by the lambda.

I have tried to sent them as headers through curl, but that does not seem to work:

> curl --header "-Amz-Invocation-Type: InvocationType" --header "X-Amz-Log-Type: LogType"  --header "x-api-key: akey" https://lambdauui.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/status/health

as all I see back is the response from the lambda itself.

Is there a way to programmatically allow the logs from the lambda to be returned (or a way to configure the lambda and/or API Gateway cloud formation to allow this)?